# Responsive adsense & bootstrap raw

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, adsense

I have a row which is divided to three columns by bootstrap , 
and I want to insert a responsive ad unite in the middle column.

the middle column doesn't have a determined width "as bootstrap do" and I cannot use JavaScript to set its width to the available width

sometime it works great , but sometime the ad unit width become larger than the middle column with , so it goes down the first column , and the third column goes under it (like a vertical list , not horizontal row)

Now what I have to do to make the width of adsense unit fit the middle column width?

Comment: Those columns which you are adding, have already be defined a width. So obviously it would break if there is something larger. What you can do instead is add a wrapper on the adsense unit and set its width to `auto`.

Comment: the same result